# A different interpretation of $E=mc^2$ but no idea what it might mean

Tags: energy, mass

I wanted $E=mc^2$ to look like an 'inverse square' sort of a formula. So this is what I derived:

$E=mc^2$, so;

$m=E/c^2$,

assuming $E=E_1E_2$ (I am aware that when you decompose energy into two multipliers the units will be different but in purely mathematical sense there should be a way of doing it) and there a constrant = A. So;

$m=A(E_1E_2)/c^2$.

And I translated this into English as such: The mass between to energies is inversely proportional with the speed of light between those two energies.

And if you use $E=(hc)/\lambda$ equation, the previous equation becomes:

$m=A(h_1/\lambda_1)(h_2/\lambda_2)$, (Maybe $h_1 = h_2$).

Do these mean anything to someone who actually knows physics? :)

Comment: $E=mc^2$ means that you have completely neglected the important part of the actual formula which, when properly written, looks like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation

Comment: Well - I _think_ I know (some) physics but those equations mean nothing to me, sorry. Just because you can do mathematical things and give them symbols that look like physical symbols does not mean they retain their meaning. In particular your step to persist in $E=hc/\lambda$ when the thing you call $E$ is not an energy, is a step I cannot fathom.

Comment: One problem here is that $E = hc/\lambda$ only works for light quanta (massless).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $E=E_1 E_2$ (I am aware that when you decompose energy into two
>   multipliers the units will be different but in purely mathematical
>   sense there should be a way of doing it)

Unfortunately, the fact that the unit $\rm J$ is not equal to the unit $\rm J^2$ is more than an inconvenience - it is a fatal flaw in your mathematics, and everything after this assumption is nonsense.  In a purely mathematical sense, you can, of course, express any number as the product of two numbers, but you can't necessarily assign them any physical significance that seems convenient.

It's easier to see why this is so by using a quantity that you may have more intuition about - length:

---

I have a rectangular plot of land.  I know that the diagonal measures 150 meters, but I want to know the area to find out how much corn seed I need to plant it.

Well, I know that the formula for the area of a rectangle is $A = s_1 s_2$, where $s_1$ and $s_2$ are the lengths of the two sides.

I also know that if I have a length $L$, then it should be possible to express it as two lengths $L = L_1 L_2$,

And I translated this into English as such:  The diagonal between two lengths of a rectangle is equal to the product of the two lengths.

So $150~\rm m = 15 ~\rm m \cdot 10 ~\rm m$, therefore my plot must have an area of $150 m^2$.  (I am aware that the units will be different, but in a purely mathematical sense there should be a way of doing it)

---

Hopefully, it's obvious that this is nonsense - given the diagonal length, the area of that rectangle could be anything from $0~\rm m^2$ to $11,250~\rm m^2$.  The mere fact that you can multiply two numbers to get a third number doesn't mean you can arbitrarily assign units, and from that deduce meaning.

If $E = E_1 E_2$, then $E$, $E_1$, and $E_2$ cannot all have units of $J$, not because I'm a stickler for notation, but because **they cannot all be measurements of energy**.  Assuming they are will lead to you to an incorrect conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

$E=hc/\lambda$ only works for photons, and $E = mc^2$ only works for stationary objects. For moving objects, we use the energy-momentum equation.